Unable to debug Flask app in docker using Pycharm and in-container interpreter
I have Pycharm pro and I'm trying to get my flask app running with breakpoints in local environment.
Here is the docker compose config:
  flask:
    container_name: sv_server
    build:
      context: .
      ssh:
        - default
      dockerfile: ./project/Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --reload -w 1 --timeout 300 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 "sv_server:create_app()"
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/var/www/html/project
      - ./bootstrap/:/var/www/html/bootstrap
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    env_file:
      - ./project/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
      - "postgres:pgsql-server"
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.flask.rule: Host(`api.project.test`)
      traefik.http.services.flask.loadbalancer.server.port: 5000
      traefik.docker.network: traefik_default

Everything work fine when I start it with docker compose up flask or with Pycharm's integrated container manager, I can access it through "api.project.test"

But for development needs, I need to run it in debug mode with breakpoints available. Following multiple tutorials, I ended up with a RUN/DEBUG config like this :

This config generates the following command when launched:
/usr/local/bin/python3 /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 172.17.0.1 --port 45065 --file /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --reload -w 1 --timeout 300 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 sv_server:create_app()

The flask container shows up in portainer and the logs seems to be ok, but my API is unreachable (through postman or browser), all the requests end up in 504 Gateway timeout, and no log shows in the container
Any advice ?
